# How can I deal with POST 403 error with React Native?

Tags: django, apache, react-native, post

My friend and I have faced a lot of errors while building up Hybrid app. We've used React Native as Frontend and django rest framework as backend 
Worst of them is 403 error when we post json file from React native to django rest framework.

when we first made POST, It could POST to API server but 403 error started to raise after moving our place.

we used AWS and apapche2. and I set permission as Allowany that means anyone can access api and do GET, POST and DELETE.

fronted code is like this

```
let data = JSON.stringify({username:"sososo",});


console.log(data)
  fetch(`http://52.78.216.37:8080/api/users/`,
    {
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      body:data,
    })
    .then(result => console.log('success====:', result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error============:', error))
}
```

backend setting.py is like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'userinfo',
    'api',
    'profiles',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'chatapp',
    'matching',
    'widget_tweaks',

]
SITE_ID = 1

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/med
```

we don't know what is main problem of 403 error..
please help us !!!!

Comment: why would you put slurs in the questions if you need help?

Comment: i do not mean to put slurs in my question. I'm very new to developing, so it's hard to make it concrete.

Comment: [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Answer (score 0):

**CSRF is causing the error**:

Set your settings with basic auth

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'= (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
),
```

This should work, but if didnt check bellow

**For Api**
To disable csrf validation use CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication which extends from the default SessionAuthentication class.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/

**For regular Views**
Use @csrf_exempt in your views to avoid csrf sucurity check, but you will probabily be vunerable to middleman attacks **NOT SAFE!**

**Example in regular views**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/